# How to improve search speed with MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, indexing, full-text-search

My website is built using Django and MySQL. The content table in the MySQL database contains nearly 20 fields, including id, title, description, content, analyze, and so on. Some of these fields are of varchar type, some are of text type, and some also store JSON data. There are now over 30000 pieces of data in the content table, with myd files accounting for approximately 33GB.

After conducting some like queries based on the above fields, I found that the search speed is very slow, possibly reaching over 2 minutes. I only indexed the ID in the content table. What should be done with such a MySQL search index to improve search speed? Or is there any other way? I originally wanted to try Elasticsearch, but the server memory is not enough.

I only indexed the ID in the content table.

Comment: you can add indexes for the fields which are using in the quires,  also check index_together ( when your select query using multiple fields in where condition),  use explain to see your query plan(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#explain) , which help to identify which indexes are using, and the time taking part, and then create index accordingly.  also install djano-debug tool bar, django-silk,  also check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/

Comment: You should add some sample code to see how you query the DB and help you improve it if needed, but also to get a better picture of your problem

Comment: In Database systems, knowing your queries is a must, no one will be able to tell you an answer without knowing your DB Design and your queries. Because the search can be slow due to a join or you are using an OR which kills the performance.

Comment: Can you obtain an explain plan for your search query? Please add that to the question, plus the CREATE TABLE for all tables involved, and the row count for each of the table(s).

Comment: This is my query sql：

db_obj = mydb.objects.filter(~Q(user= username) & Q(title__icontains=kw)).order_by('-id').values(‘title’,’id’,’icon’,’time’,’user’)[:100].iterator()

Answer (score 1):

- Use ENGINE=InnoDB, not MyISAM.
- What column(s) takes a megabyte (per row)?  If the search does not need to look at the big column, let's discuss restructuring the schema to avoid it.
- Let's see the type of search you want to do.  Then we can discuss making a suitable `INDEX` to speed up the query.
- If `Q(title__icontains=kw)` turns into `WHERE title LIKE '%kw%'`, then it will be terribly slow due to having to fetch and check every `title`.
- If `~Q(user= username)` means `NOT user = "username"`, then no index will help.

Comment: This is my query sql. I have set the index and it has no effect: 

db_obj = mydb.objects.filter(~Q(user= username) & Q(title__icontains=kw)).order_by('-id').values(‘title’,’id’,’icon’,’time’,’user’)[:100].iterator()

Comment: I added some stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much! So it seems that I can only use another database

Comment: The query as I understand it will require a full table scan by any database server.  I doubt if it will be faster elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

In order to make your queries fast. You should try [database normalization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFQaEYEc8_8&ab_channel=Decomplexify). Detect the columns which are used to filter tables frequently, and apply indexing on them.

Database normalization and indexing most searched columns will make your queries fast, and also it will not cost much storage.

But also make sure not to add too many indexes in a database table as it will lengthen the write speed (if you are also concerned about write speed).

Comment: how to try database normalisation

Comment: @YaHuang i added a video link in the comment, please check. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use database indexing in your django models

Comment: I have already set indexes in both django and mysql, but it has no effect